# Angularjs - Update select model from controller gives error

Tags: angularjs

HTML Code:

```
<select  ng-model='currentProject'  ng-repeat='project in projects'>
    <option value=''>Choose a project</option>
</select>
```

Variable projects is an array of strings. Now, when I add an item to projects in controller and update the model, I get an error that array has duplicates.

In controller:

```
$scope.projects.push($scope.newProject);
$scope.currentProject =  $scope.newProject;
```

Error thrown by AngularJS:

```
Duplicates in a repeater are not allowed. Use 'track by' expression to specify unique keys. Repeater: project in projects
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

In your `ng-repeat` replace it with `project in projects track by $index` read more about `track by` here https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat